# Update a preprint on ResearchGate to conference publication after acceptance

Tags: conference, online-publication, preprint

Is there a way to update a `preprint` on ResearchGate to the published conference version including accepted conference information etc.? I have not found a straightforward way to do this, I don't think deleting the preprint and replacing it with the conference version is a good solution especially if the preprint already has followers, comments etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Researchgate requesting to them merge two papers once (a preprint and a postprint). All they did was to delete one of the papers (unfortunately the 'better' of the two). Not recommended. Instead, I would suggest you either update the previous upload or upload a second version, preferably both. Update the old for your followers. I can't say for sure, but I think new uploads get some priority in the feed of other users. By performing both these actions you maximize the exposure your paper gets.

Comment: Wow, that is sad, losing a better version. For now I have adopted your suggestion, i.e. uploaded the current one separately, thou this results to duplicates, however both versions slightly differ in content.

Comment: Yeah. Having duplicates is not ideal, but I think it is the best solution for now. Especially in the short term, you benefit from the extra attention to your paper(s). Hopefully Researchgate will add more functionality in the future, including the option to merge two papers manually.